# Problems with understanding scope

Tags: c++

I|m having problems understanding the scope of a class or a function. This program is incomplete but I am not being able to use a function within the same class and then from a different class. For example: I get an error that says

> "'selector' was not declared in this scope"

Can you help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;       

int main(void){
selector();

}  

void selector(){
    linkedList test;
    /* block of code */           
 }  

class linkedList{
   Node *head; 
public:
  linkedList(){
    head = NULL;
    }
    //other lines
 };

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node * next;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior**, a specific problem or **error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Scopes in C++ work the same way as they do in java. What's your specific problem?

Comment: There is no class!

Comment: @manni66 do i need a class to hold the main function? These two are supposed to be in the same class. I did not include the other classes because i could not move past this.

Comment: @ShrijeshSiwakoti `main` is definitely not supposed to be in any class.

Comment: main has to be a function, as in your code. You are talking about classes, but there is none.

Comment: @manni66 i updated the question to show what my classes look like.

Comment: And what's the meaning of _function within the same class and then from a different class_ in this context?

Comment: @manni66 by within the same class, i meant using the selector function from main and by different class i meant creating a node object within linkedlist. Its now working after i swapped the order of the classes or functions. Thanks!

Comment: Selector isn't a function of any class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're talking about classes, but the scope of a function is from its declaration to the end of the file. Just swap the two functions in your code:

```
void selector() {
    // linkedList test;
    /* block of code */           
}

int main() {
    selector();  // selector is in scope here
}
```

(I'm not sure why you're doing `int main(void)` either. That's more of a C thing. A C++ function with no arguments looks like `int main()`.)

Comment: Thanks i didn't know about the order. This might work. I did not include classes in the code before, because I could not check if sth was wrong with that yet.